# OpenCL Kernel Usage (Operations-to-Data Transfer ratio)

Tags: opencl

I am intending to implement a OpenCL kernel function and depending on the computations (Operations-to-Data Transfer ratio) to accomplish within this function, I'd like to determine it's worth to proceed so. Therefore, on my estimation, I found that the Operations-to-Data Transfer ratio is about 12-15 which will be constant whatever the dimension of the data input/output to transfer between the Host and the Device.

For this case, do you think that it's better to do the computation from the Host or the Device?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without more details, one can only wildly guess... Depends on what do you mean by "operations" (OpenCL level ? GPU instruction level ?), "data transfers" (bytes/WItem please), whether you can use local memory, what hardware exactly is the Host and what hardware is the Device...

Comment: Agreed. Additionally, what data types are we talking about? Pretty much all GPUs are good at 32-bit float operations. It starts diverging when you get into integer operations of various sizes or 16-bit (half) floats, and can be wildly different for double-precision (64-bit) floating-point values. Also, some types of tasks are inherently a lot more suitable to GPU-style parallelism than others.

Comment: I am using basically float as data type and the operations are basically sum, divide, multiplication, logarithm and atan formula. So, i just count the number of those operations just to know the ratio Operations to Data transfer

Comment: @Abdoulayendiongue It's not so simple. I'm 99% certain OpenCL's atan() is not implemented in hardware on any common GPU (or CPU) today, and will be computed using a dozen (or several dozens) of instructions. log() exists in hardware at least on AMD, but it may not be IEEE754-compliant everywhere, which means again OpenCL could use a library implementation. So this means your OpenCL program will be >= 100 instructions. So depending on how much actual data transfers from-to global mem you're doing per WItem, this might be worthwhile to do on GPU.

Comment: BTW there is a way to use native hardware instructions for certain operations by prefixing with "native_" - but again this depends on hardware, plus it's precision and domain are completely HW-dependent (and usually pretty bad).

BTW 2: modern CPUs don't have instructions for atan() or log() or anything transcendental, so your program will NOT have less instructions on a CPU.

Comment: Thanks @mogu . It means that such functions as atan() and log() require so many elementary operations that it's worth to put it on GPU in order to execute them on parallel way.